# When I run my Selenium program it is showing errors how to solve this?

Tags: java, selenium

When I run my selenium program its showing errors how to solve this?

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class sss {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.diver", "E:\\Selenium Project\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email"));
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at FirefoxDriver.get(FirefoxDriver.java:21)
    at sss.main(sss.java:13)`enter code here`
C:\Users\Gaurav PC\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: FireFox Browser: 53.0.2 (32-bit)
Selenium: 2.9.1
Geckodriver: geckodriver-v0.16.1-win64

Comment: Can you try bumping up to Selenium 3.4.0, geckodriver v0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox 53.x?

Comment: so version is not compatible is this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for you:

1. To work with `geckodriver` v0.16.1 you need to have Selenium 3.4 or greater.
   You can view the release notes [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).
2. Download the latest Selenium 3.4.0 from [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
3. Install the stable & compatible Mozila Firefox.
4. Instead of using the `FirefoxDriver` implementation you should use the `WebDriver` interface.
5. Review your code before you start the execution. It should have been `webdriver.gecko.driver` instead of `webdriver.gecko.diver`
6. Your code will look like:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.get("http://gmail.com");
   ```

Let me know if this answers your question.